# Issue with Delete in Aurora RDS AWS , Long Execution Time for Single Row Deletion in Amazon Aurora MYSQL

Tags: amazon-aurora

I'm experiencing an unusually long execution time when trying to delete a single record from a table in Amazon Aurora (Server-Less). The table is large (around 2 billion records), but the query is straightforward and uses the primary key.

Query:

sql

DELETE FROM cc_list WHERE id = '1904746137';
EXPLAIN Output:

sql

Type: Range, Possible Keys: PRIMARY, Key: PRIMARY, Key_len: 8, Rows: 1, Extra: Using where
Despite the query's simplicity and the use of an index, it takes over 900 seconds and often results in a lock wait timeout.

I've tried the following:

Ensuring id is indexed (primary key).
Checking for locks and long-running transactions.
Monitoring database performance and load.
Running the query during low-traffic periods.

My DB memorey is 196 GB
Any suggestions on why this might be happening or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Ensuring id is indexed (primary key).
Checking for locks and long-running transactions.
Monitoring database performance and load.
Running the query during low-traffic periods.

My DB memory is 196 GB

Comment: Amazon aurora is compatible with mysql amd postgresql, but is neither of the above.

Comment: Were other queries accessing the same table at the same time?  _If_ they had a lock on _that_ row, then it might explain the issue.

Comment: there is no query is running in same time , only the delete query (1 query )

Comment: I suggest turning on slow query logs, which will tell you where the execution time is being allocated https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_LogAccess.MySQL.LogFileSize.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQL.Generallog